# Maximum power of $2$ which divides $3^{1024}-1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

What is the maximum power of $2$ which completely divides $3^{1024}-1$?

I proceeded thus:
$\phi(2^n)=2^{n-1}$ for all $n\ge1$
$$3^{1024}=3^{2^{10}}\equiv1\pmod {2^{11}}$$
$$3^{1024}-1\equiv0\pmod {2^{11}}$$
Since $\phi(2^{11})=2^{10}$.  So, maximum power of $2$ must be $11$.
But the answer says it is $12$.
Where am I wrong and how to solve it correctly?

Comment: Your argument shows that $2^{11}$ divides the number, not that it is maximal.

Comment: Then how to find the maximum value?

Comment: Hint:  note that $x^{1024}-1=(x-1)\times \prod_{i=0}^9 \left(x^{2^i}+1\right)$ and remark that every term is $2\pmod 4$ except for $x+1$ when you take $x=3$.

Comment: @lulu That means that every term is divisible by $2$ except $(3+1)$ which is divisible by $4$. So maximum power$=12$. But I have $2$ doubts:

Comment: @lulu 1) What is that formula you used at the beggining?

Comment: @lulu 2) Why take $\pmod{4}$ instead of any other number?

Comment: You have to establish that my factoring is correct (it was a hint, not a full solution).  it's obvious that each factor is even (when $x=3$).  A priori, some of the factors might be divisible by a high power of $2$, so you look $\mod 4$ to rule that out .

Comment: @lulu Please consider making this an answer.

Comment: @lulu comments are not for answers, and not really for hints either. Especially not hints which basically outline the entire solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As requested in the comments:

We start by factoring the polynomial $x^{1024}-1$.  To do that, we note that $1$ is a root, as is every $2^k-$root of $1$ for $k=0,\cdots 10$.  For $k>0$ such a root of unity is also a $2^{k-1}-$st root of $-1$ so our polynomial is divisible by $$(x-1)\times \prod_{k=0}^9(x^{2^k}+1)$$

Comparing the lead terms shows that this is in fact equal to our polynomial.

Now, let $x=3$.   We remark that $$3\equiv -1 \pmod 4 \implies 3^{2i}+1\equiv 2 \mod 4$$ so most of the terms in the product are divisible by $2$ but not by $4$.  $3-1=2$, of course, and $3+1=4$ is the only term in the product divisible by a higher power of $2$.  $(3-1)(3+1)$ then gives us a factor of $2^3$ and the other nine terms in the product each give us exactly one factor of $2$, making the answer $12$ as desired.

Comment: Rather than going into complex roots of unity, considering the target audience, I personally believe it's better to go with $(x^{512})^2-1=(x^{512}-1)(x^{512}+1)=\cdots$.

Comment: (+1) I think my answer is the same except without the $x$s; however, it is a bit more general, too.

Answer (score 2):

Just to give a different approach, since $3^4=81=1+80=1+5\cdot2^4$, we have

$$3^{1024}-1=(1+80)^{256}-1=256\cdot80+{256\choose2}80^2+{256\choose3}80^3+\cdots\\
=2^8(5\cdot2^4)+(2^7\cdot255)(5^2\cdot2^8)+(2^7\cdot85\cdot254)(5^3\cdot2^{12})+\cdots\\
\equiv5\cdot2^{12}\mod2^{13}$$

all terms after the first having higher and higher powers of $2$. Thus $3^{1024}-1$ is divisible by $2^{12}$ but not by $2^{13}$.

Answer (score 2):

For $n\ge1$,
$$
3^{2^n}-1
=\underbrace{\left(3^{2^0}-1\right)}_2\underbrace{\left(3^{2^0}+1\right)}_4\underbrace{\left(3^{2^1}+1\right)}_{2\bmod4}\underbrace{\left(3^{2^2}+1\right)}_{2\bmod4}\cdots\underbrace{\left(3^{2^{n-1}}+1\right)}_{2\bmod4}
$$
Thus, for $n\ge1$,
$$
\left.2^{n+2}\,\middle|\,3^{2^n}-1\right.
$$
but that
$$
\left.2^{n+3}\not\,\middle|\,3^{2^n}-1\right.
$$

Answer (score 0):

If $2^n$ divides $3^{1024}-1$, then $3$ has order at most $1024=2^{10}$, mod $2^n$.

Now, $3$ has order $2^{n-2}$ mod $2^n$. (*)

So, $n-2=10$ is the maximum possible, that is, $n=12$.

(*) By induction, $3^{2^{n-3}} \equiv 1+2^{n-1} \bmod 2^n$ and $3^{2^{n-2}} \equiv 1 \bmod 2^n$ for $n\ge 4$.